# Should I treat e-mails as case sensitive when searching for duplicates in the database?

Tags: php, database, email

In my website I have a signup/login page, I was asking about whether I should treat the emails as case sensitive when searching for duplicates in the database to prevent the duplication of emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't treat them as case sensitive.

I think some RFC says that the username-part of an email suppose to be case sensitive. However, in reality, I've never come across any mail server that follows that rule (for good reasons).